# Why is matlab giving me a single answer when I divide by a vector?

Tags: fourier-series, matlab

I'm attempting to do a stem plot of $\frac{sin(k2D\pi)}{k\pi}$ in matlab.

Following is my procedure:

```
x = linspace(-50,50);
D = 1/8;
Y = (sin(x*2*pi*D))/(x*pi);
stem(Y)
```

But rather than giving me what I would expect(Fourier Series coefficients for a square wave with duty cycle D), I get a single delta. I checked Y, and it's saying it's equal to 1.9987e-04, rather than a vector like I would expect.

If I remove the /(x*pi) from Y, I get a vector like I would expect. What's wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform pointwise divison of two vectors, use the $./$ operator instead of the $/$ operator:

```
Y = (sin(x*2*pi*D)) ./ (x*pi);
```

Comment: I assume "pointwise" means x[i] = a[i]/b[i] ?

Comment: Also, what was happening when I used normal division? It did give me an answer, was it just using the first index for each?

Comment: Yes. According to MATLAB's documentation (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html), it was treating `sin(x*2*pi*D)` as a $1 \times 100$ matrix $B$, treating `x*pi` as a $1 \times 100$ matrix $A$, and finding the least-squares solution to solve for the $1 \times 1$ scalar $\hat x$ in the equation $xA = B$.